# How to return Parse promise from cloud code module?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, module, cloud, promise

Would anyone know how to return the result of a Promise from a cloud code module? I am using the examples [here](https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-with-third-party-services) but it keeps telling me that options is undefined (or nothing if I check with if(options) first.

I am calling the function with `module.function` as a promise, but still not getting results.

And ideas?

Edit: I can FORCE it to work but calling:

```
module.function({},{
 success:function(res){
  //do something
 }, 
 error:function(err){
  //handle error
 }
})
```

but this isn't really great since 1) I have to stick the empty object in there 2) I can't force the object to work like a promise and therefore lose my ability to chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if the issue is with modules or promises.  Here's some code that illustrates both, creating a module with a function that returns a promise, then calling that from a cloud function.

Create a module like this:

```
// in 'cloud/somemodule.js'

// return a promise to find instances of SomeObject
exports.someFunction = function(someValue) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("SomeObject");
    query.equalTo("someProperty", someValue);
    return query.find();
};
```

Include the module by requiring it:

```
// in 'cloud/main.js'
var SomeModule = require('cloud/somemodule.js');

Parse.Cloud.define("useTheModule", function(request, response) {
    var value = request.params.value;
    // use the module by mentioning it
    // the promise returned by someFunction can be chained with .then()
    SomeModule.someFunction(value).then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue seemed to just be having the `then` in the module instead of `main.js`